# Python - Jira login issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, jira, python-jira

I'm a newbie to python, trying my hands on python - Jira,

I have the below code,

```
def login_jira(un, pwd):
 return JIRA(basic_auth=(un, pwd), options={'server':'jiraUrL'})
```

When I try to execute, it throws the below error

`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Not sure what's messing up!

Comment: is `JIRA` a string?

Comment: I use - ```from jira import JIRA```

Comment: try either printing the `JIRA`, or printing the `type(JIRA)` to check out the type of it. If it wont work, add the code which calls to this method.

Comment: Even before calling the basic auth, tried - ```print(type(JIRA))``` and it printed ```<class 'str'>```

Comment: Ideally it should be ```<class 'type'>``` ?

Comment: It's likely you have a str variable named JIRA, probably containing the URL?

Comment: Aah that was the prob.. Had a another string varible with name JIRA..